# Use directshow filter in other windows OS

Tags: windows-7, filter, windows-ce, directshow

I compiled DirectShow filter in Windows7.
Can I use this DLL filter in Wince or I need to compile it in Wince and then I'll be able to use it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Win CE runs on ARM and MIPS chips, so you will have to recompile.

Comment: This isn't he answer I hoped to get :)